# Finding Orthonormal System

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $$\langle f,g \rangle=f(0)\overline{g(0)}+\int_{0}^1 f'(x)\overline{g'(x)}dx$$ over $C^{1}[0,1]$ find an orthonormal system $\{h_1,h_2,h_3\}$ s.t $$Span\{h_1,h_2,h_3\}=Span\{1,x,x^2\}$$

I have started with checking $\{1,x,x^2\}$ which is not orthogonal, So the only way is to use Gram–Schmidt process?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is the way to go.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is THE algorithm to this kind of computation.

Comment: @humanStampedist The only way?

Comment: @gbox I think unless you have some prior information or intuition about what the form of the orthonormal basis should be (which might be possible, say, in the case of the Chebyshev polynomials), G-S is the only recourse.